# Ultra Powerfull Vibrato Montecarlo for delta sensitivities of a not regular payoff

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, monte-carlo, sensitivities

Ciao,

I am working on a derivative with the following payoff at time $T$:

$$
\sqrt{(S_T - K)^+}
$$
[image]

where $S_T$ is the value of the stock at the expiring date.
As usual we will assume $S_t$ to be a GBM:

$$
dS_T = \sigma S_T dW_T
$$

> I am interested in computing greeks, in particular $\delta$ sensitivities and I decided to do it by using Vibrato Montecarlo methods and LRM techinque.

By doing a discretization of time in $N$ we can associate $T$ to $N-th$ step and $T-dt$ to $N-1 th$ step.

I've studied the structure of conditional expectation at time $T-dt$. By standard integration we can easily write:

$$
S_N = S_{N-1} \exp\left( -\frac{\sigma^2}{2}dt + \sigma \sqrt{dt}Z\right)
$$

where $Z \sim N(0, 1)$.

Of course we can also express $S_N$ in terms of $S_0$:

$$
S_N = S_0 \exp\left( -\frac{\sigma^2}{2}T + \sigma \sqrt{T}Z\right)
$$

Depending on choice we do we get different distribution for $S_N$. In the first case we have:
$$
p_{S_{N}, S_{N-1}}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma \sqrt{dt} x}\exp \left( - \frac{ \left(\ln(x) + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}dt - \ln(S_{N-1})\right)^2}{2\sigma^2 dt} \right)
$$
i.e. a log normal distribution with mean $-\frac{\sigma^2dt}{2} + \ln(S_{N-1})$ and standard deviation $\sigma \sqrt{dt}$.

In the second case we have:

$$
p_{S_{N}, S_{0}}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma \sqrt{T} x}\exp \left( - \frac{ \left(\ln(x) + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}T - \ln(S_0)\right)^2}{2\sigma^2 T} \right)
$$

> > > > > Of course the distribution is smooth wrt $S_0$ and **but the payoff is not**.
> > > > >           More over the payoff function
> > > > >           $$
> > > > > f(x, K) = \sqrt{ (x-K)^+ } 
> > > > > $$
> > > > >           is different from usual call option pay off $(x-K^+)$ since its derivative has integrability issue due to the square root.
> > > > >           That's why I am trying to do the computation via Vibrato Montecarlo, but I have still trouble as I write below

[Giles](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/files/mcqmc08.pdf) (the Great) explains that for a given parameter $\theta$ we can compute the sensitivity even if payoff is discontinuous by using LRM:

$$
\partial_\theta \mathbb{E} \left[ f(S_T) \right]  = \partial_\theta \int f(S_T) p(S_T, \theta) dS_T = \int f(S_T) \partial_\theta \log\left( p(S_T, \theta)\right) p(S_T, \theta) dS_T = \mathbb{E} \left[ f(S_T) \log\left( p(S_T, \theta)\right) \right] 
$$

Until know I've just used the usual procedure of Vibrato Montecarlo.
 Now my question:

> How should I behave in case I have to compute delta sensitivity? Infact in this case the derivative can not "pass over" $f(S_T)$ term since it depends on the paramter (which is $S_{N-1}$).

The problem here is that $f$ is not differentiable so that I am messed up at this point.

Notice that I've asked [this question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/40824/application-of-vibrato-montecarlo-methods) few time ago but in the answer [Quantuple](https://quant.stackexchange.com/users/19887/quantuple) asked for some regularity for payoff function $h$.

Comment: When trating $S_T$ as a random variable, $f(S_T)$ does not depend on $S_0$, but $p(S_T)$ does.

Comment: @Gordon I do not understand. In my case both payoff and distribution depend on $S_{T-1}$ so that both depend on $S_0$. Can you give details about what do you mean? Thx

Comment: By treating $S_T$ as a random variable, and then derive its density $f$, you will notice the density depends on $S_0$. Then $E(f(S_T) = \int_0^{\infty} x f(x, S_0) dx$.

Comment: @Gordon I see what are you saying. $S_T$ can be of course expressed in terms of $S_0$ in the same way I have wrote it in term of $S_{T-1}$. But if I do as you said, i.e. the standard integration, I came up with a not differential function in the integral. Remember that I have to integrate the expected value wrt $S_0$. This is why I am trying to use vibrato Montecarlo

Comment: The density is a smooth function of $S_0$.

Comment: @Gordon I've modified the question with more details. I think you do not get the problem since you are focusing on the wrong term, the distribution, while I'm stressing the fact that the problem is on the payoff. If you want try to answer, please do it but with a complete and formal solution (not in the comment section!)